# Fastest way to access a 3 indices array

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, memory-management

I have a linear array that contains volume data. The data are grey-level, i.e. integers values from 0 to 255.

```
int width  = 100;
int height = 100;
int depth  = 100;

int *texture3DVolume = new int[width*height*depth];
memset(texture3DVolume,0,sizeof(int)*width*height*depth);
```

I'm filling some part of the array with spherical regions of constant value:

```
    int radius= 5;
    int radius2=radius*radius;
    int centerx =  // some value in [5-95] 
    int centery =  // some value in [5-95] 
    int centerz =  // some value in [5-95] 

    int cxmin=centerx-radius;
    int cxmax=centerx+radius;
    int cymin=centery-radius;
    int cymax=centery+radius;
    int czmin = centerz-radius;
    int czmax = centerz+radius;

    for ( int x= cxmin; x<cxmax; x++)
    {
        int x2 = (x-centerx)*(x-centerx);
        for ( int y=cymin; y<cymax; y++)
        {
            int x2y2= x2+(y-centery)*(y-centery);
            int slice =  textureSizeX* y + x;
            for ( int z=czmin; z<czmax; z++)
            {
                int x2y2z2 = x2y2+(z-centerz)*(z-centerz);
                if ( x2y2z2  < radius2 )
                {
                    texture3DVolume[ txty*z+slice]=255;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that I need to access the linear array enhancing the cache locality. I think that this approach, although correct is not the fastest because in the inner loop on `z` I'd need to loop over contiguous values which in my case are not since `txty*z` *jump* for every iteration of `txty`.

How should I modify the loop to enhance data access locality?

Comment: What are `txty` and `textureSizeX` assigned to?

Comment: Not quite related to your question, but if you only have values between 0 and 255, you could consider using `char` instead of `int` (or some sort of int8).

Comment: `txty=width*height` and `textureSizeX=width` it was just a name convention to make the question simpler.

I've changed the loop nesting and made the x loop the innermost and the thing is 2x faster!

Answer (score 1):

you should use a `std::array`, if possible

```
array<array<array<int, 100>, 100>, 100> texture3DVolume;
```

Then, you should write your loops in a way, that the innermost coordinate is also the innermost loop. Assuming, that you have checked, that your min and max are within the array's boundaries you get, e.g.:

```
for (size_t z=czmin; z<czmax; ++z)
{
    for (size_t y=cymin; z<cymax; ++y)
    {
        for (size_t x=cxmin; z<cxmax; ++x)
        {
            texture3DVolume[z][y][x] = 255;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Corollary:  If you ever find yourself writing in FORTRAN, it can be useful to remember that FORTRAN orders indices in the reverse direction (x, y, z) to maximise cache hits.

Comment: My question was about indexing a linear array, not changing the definition of it.